# Custom Image sizing in WordPress theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am having some trouble with a preset image size in WordPress. I was matching the design on the homepage with the agentpress 2.0 theme by StudioPress.

I found that I could customize the preset image sizes in the functions.php file of the theme. That worked fine until I realized the image size preset that I changed I still needed for the interior pages. I think simply switched it back to it's original dimensions and created a new one for the custom size I needed for the homepage. That seemed to work for the homepage but the interior pages are still taking on the old dimensions. It is as if the site is cached or something except I am not using a caching plugin. When I check the source it is indeed the old dimensions.

Here is a link to the page:  http://districtdesigngroup.com/fox-realty/?status=for-sale
Here is a link to the demo:  http://demo.studiopress.com/agentpress/status/for-sale

You will see the thumbnail is not looking correct.

Is there a way to reset the theme or something to make these changes take effect? What is wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what you mean, but if you wish to re-generate your existing thumbnails so their sizes are readapted according to the new dimensions you have defined in Settings>Media or in functions.php (with add_image_size), just use the WordPress plugin "Regenerate Thumbnails". It works brilliantly (I used it many times before). It will take the original source images and regenerate all thumbnails at all defined image sizes. I hope I understood what your problem is.